# GTM (firebase) tracking of app open event and campaign in android

Tags: android, firebase-analytics, android-architecture-components, event-tracking

I need to add some tracking events to my android app. I am using GTM and sending events via firebase with `FirebaseAnalyitcs.getInstance(Context).logEvent()`. To just make it easier in the following the events to be send are called ***app_open*** and ***open_campaign***.
***app_open*** needs to be called every time the app goes into the foreground BUT not if a deep link url contains campaign parameters. Then ***open_campaign*** has to be tracked. As far as I understand the reason behind this is that when ***app_open*** is tracked a new session is created in firebase(GTM) and if then ***open_campaign*** would be tracked again a second session is created so we have one "useless" session with a duration of less then 1 second.

My question now is how to prevent this double tracking in an easy and nice way?

The current approach to track ***app_open*** is to use a `LifecycleObserver` and add it to the `ProcessLifecycleOwner` in the application class.

```
class ApplicationLifecycleObserver : LifecycleObserver {
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun onBackground() {
        //nothing to do
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun onForeground() {
        trackAppOpen()
    }
}

// in application class
override fun onCreate() {
...
    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(ApplicationLifecycleObserver())
...
}
```

But here I don't know anything about deep links or campaigns at all. So how could I prevent the ***app_open*** event to be tracked in case of a campaign deeplink?

I think I am not the first one to have this problem :) So maybe some of you can point me into the right direction on how to implement those tracking events properly. :)

Thank you,
Peter